# Delete button not working flask sqlalchemy

Tags: html, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

So I've got a settings page where the user can change their password and email which works fine but I also have a delete account button but it doesn't work and I want to know why and what's wrong with my code so can anyone tell me ?? Here is my code in the routes file:

```
@app.route('/studentsettings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def studentsettings():
    form = settingsform1(request.form, obj=current_user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
     if  "savedetails" in request.form and form.validate_on_submit():
 
       
        current_user.password = form.password.data
        current_user.email = form.email.data
        
        current_user.set_password(form.password.data)
        
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Your details have been changed.')
        return redirect(url_for('studentsettings'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        
        form.password.data = current_user.password_hash
        form.email.data = current_user.email
        
    return render_template('studentsettings.html', title='Student settings',
                           form=form)
def delete(current_user):
    deleteform = deleteform(request.form, obj=current_user)
    return render_template('studentsettings.html', deleteform=deleteform,obj=current_user)
    if  "deleteaccount" in request.form and form.validate_on_submit():
   
        obj = Object.query.get_or_404(current_user)
        delete(obj)
        db.session.commit()

        flash('Your account has been successfully deleted. ', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

    return render_template('login.html', deleteform=deleteform, obj=current_user)
```

I have this in the forms file:

```
class deleteform(Form):
    delete = SubmitField()
```

Here is the code for the delete button in the html page:

```
<table>
<div style="padding-bottom:5%">
    <tr><td>  <h3>Delete account:</h3></td></tr>
<form action="{{ url_for('delete', current_user=obj.current_user) }}" method="post">
 {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
  <tr><td> <p><input type="submit" id="deleteaccount" name="deleteaccount" value="Delete account"></p></td></tr>
    
</form>
```

This is the error message that I'm getting:

```
[2021-06-16 11:29:22,752] ERROR in app: Exception on /studentsettings [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask_login\utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\routes.py", line 153, in studentsettings
    return render_template('studentsettings.html', title='Student settings',
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 137, in render_template
    return _render(
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\iptutorial\app\templates\studentsettings.html", line 160, in top-level template code
    <form action="{{ url_for('delete', current_user=obj.current_user) }}" method="post">
  File "C:\Users\uSDDE\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'obj' is undefined
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Jun/2021 11:29:22] "←[35m←[1mGET /studentsettings HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
```

Comment: I don't see you passing obj in the template in delete function nor I see your routes.

Comment: You write: ```{{ url_for('delete', current_user=obj.current_user) }}``` Two things: 1. You do not pass obj to the render_template function, so jinja does not know obj and throws ```is undefined```. 2. What should be the URL be for ```delete```? There is no route added.

Comment: I want it to be in the same route as student settings because that's the page it's on, just with two separate functions and I did put obj in the render template function for the delete function but it still gives me that error message. So what now??